# buffergeometry with more than 40k vertices

Tags: three.js

I was loading more than `40k vertices` in a `BufferGeometry`.

It worked, but the geometry was not rendered entirely. After decomposing the geometry into separate chunks of `40k vertices`, it worked. I was using `version r86`.

Is this something related to the hardware I am using or to three `js`?

Please find bellow an adaptation of the code I used to create the `BufferGeometry` (normalgeom is a Geometry passed as parameter)

```
var positions = new Float32Array(chunkLength * 3);
var indices = new Uint16Array(chunkLength);
var chunkLength = normalgeom.vertices.length;
for (var i = 0; i < chunkLength; i++)
{
    var posInNormalGeom = i;
    positions[i * 3] = normalgeom.vertices[posInNormalGeom].x;
    positions[i * 3 + 1] = normalgeom.vertices[posInNormalGeom].y;
    positions[i * 3 + 2] = normalgeom.vertices[posInNormalGeom].z;
    indices[i] = i;
}

var buffGeom = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
buffGeom.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3));
buffGeom.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Uint16Array(indices), 1));
```

Afterwards, I was creating LineSegments from the buffer

```
var lineSegs = new THREE.LineSegments(buffGeom, material);
scene.add(lineSegs);
```

Update: after comment from @TheJim01, the code for splitting the geometry is the following

```
function makebuffered(normalgeom)
{
    var retArrays = new Array();

    var chunkLength = normalgeom.vertices.length;
    console.log("nr vertices:" + chunkLength);
    var remainingVertices = chunkLength;
    var processedVertices = 0;
    if(chunkLength > 40000)
    {
        chunkLength = 40000;
    }

    while(remainingVertices > 0)
    {
        if(remainingVertices <= chunkLength)
        {
            chunkLength = remainingVertices;
        }

        var positions = new Float32Array(chunkLength * 3);
        var indices = new Uint32Array(chunkLength);
        for (var i = 0; i < chunkLength; i++)
        {
            var posInNormalGeom = processedVertices + i;
            positions[i * 3] = normalgeom.vertices[posInNormalGeom].x;
            positions[i * 3 + 1] = normalgeom.vertices[posInNormalGeom].y;
            positions[i * 3 + 2] = normalgeom.vertices[posInNormalGeom].z;
            indices[i] = i;
        }

        var buffGeom = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
        buffGeom.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3));
        buffGeom.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Uint32Array(indices), 1));

        retArrays.push(buffGeom);

        remainingVertices -= chunkLength;
        processedVertices += chunkLength;
    }

    return retArrays;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how you imported the data? Maybe add a code-example?

Comment: I updated the question with code example.

Comment: Try using a `Uint32Array` for your indices. You may be going beyond the maximum value for `Uint16Array`, which would result in missing faces.

Comment: @TheJim01: Now that you mention it, it makes sense. Thank you. I have not noticed that I am using 16bit indices.

Comment: Did this resolve your issue? If so, please let us know, and I'll add it as a "real" answer.

Comment: @TheJim01: I did as you suggested, but it is still not satisfying. The geometry has 847666 vertices. Please see the updated code in the question.

Comment: Do you know how many indices it produces? That's the defining metric.

Comment: @TheJim01: does the updated function in the question answer you question?

Comment: I see. So you should have 847666 indices as well. I'm going to suggest something that may seem counter-intuitive: Try commenting out `buffGeom.setIndex(...);`. A while back, I had a buffer that wasn't working when using indexing, but worked correctly when I removed indexing. Because your indexing is 1:1 with your vertices, it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @TheJim01: in the updated example I forgot another 16 bit array (corrected now). So, you initial answer was correct. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @sandualuclopotaru Why are you breaking your geometry into chunks? Why are you setting indices if you are not sharing vertices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 847666 vertices, which leads to 847666 indices, which is well beyond the bounds of a `Uint16Array` (max = 65535).

To alleviate this, use `Uint32Array` instead. All modern browsers (of any consequence) support 32-bit arrays for WebGL buffers.